# Is it possible to show my GitHub contributions from work profile in my private profile?

Tags: git, github

My company asks every employee to work from another GitHub account with company email address. Work repositories are all private.

`git config --get --global user.email` returns my private email address (user.name returns private Github nickname)

`git config --get user.email` in company repo returns my work email address (user.name returns work nickname)

Is there a way to show activity from work profile in my private profile? I know that I can change user.email for every commit in all work repos to my private email, but that will be really strange. Do I have any chances to see green contribution tiles on my private GitHub account from work one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show contributions to private repositories in addition of your contributions to public ones ("[Publicizing or hiding your private contributions on your profile](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile)")

But you cannot show contributions from another account (ie your work profile) from your private profile: those are two different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

[Add an another email address to your GitHub account.](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account)

And you will be able to see contributions.